# Multiple reads with Network LocationProvider

Tags: android, location, android-location

If I only use the Network provider to get locations makes sense to do two or three consecutive reads to get the best one?

Or it's a waste of time and I can get the same with only a simple requestSingleUpdate()?
In my tests with my device/phone company seems that multiple reads return very similar locations but I'm not sure if it's always true.

Answer (score 0):

A priori, there is no reason for a method to return different results via successive calls. 
Where did you hear about this technique ?

Use a fine grained location provider if available and listen for location changes.

That should be enough.

Comment: In network provider I don't think so. But when you receive GPS location fixes it takes some time to receive good ones, doesn't it?

Comment: It kind of reminds me something but I never verified it personally. So the solution could be to open a time frame during which you take fixes and keep the average location when you want to know where the device is.